# Bash ввод переменных в кавычках

Tags: bash

При вызове скрипта в Bash вводятся переменные (символьные). Необходимо перевести их в Заглавные буквы и создать Акроним.
Например: привет мир
Результат: ПМ
Если есть дефис-слова разбить на отдельные. Если есть тире-игнорировать.
Как бы решил,но запнулся на одном месте:
если вводятся переменные в одиночных кавычках ('привет мир'), они считаются одной переменной и не бьются на отдельные. Никак не могу это обойти. Кавычки нужно игнорить.
Вот скрипт:

```
 count=$#
for  ((i=1; i<=count; i++))
do
K="${!i}"
K="${!i//_/''}"

if [[ "$K" != "-" ]]; then
   if [[ "$K" = *-* ]]; then
        var+="${K:0:1}"
        t="${K##*-}"
        var+="${t:0:1}"
   else
        var+="${K:0:1}"
   fi
fi
done
echo "$var" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

Answer (score 0):

для начала, у вас написанно:

```
tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

а судя по описанию вам нужно преобразовывать не тока английские однобайтовые символы но и другие символы Unicode, но обычный `tr` не будет понимать/преобразовывать те же многобайтные символы кирилицы.

саму задачу проще решить по другому, к примеру так:

```
echo "$*" |tr -d '_' |tr '-' ' ' |awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";FS="";}{printf toupper($1)}'
```